# how to stop timer with another function javascript

Tags: javascript, html, timer, timing

So I have this code

```
function timer()
{
     setTimeout(function(){alert("Out of time")}, 3000); //Alerts "Out of time" after 3000 milliseconds
}
function resetTime()
{
     timer(); //this is not right, i thought it would override the first function but it just adds another timer as well which is not what I want
}
function stopTime()
{
     //What could go here to stop the first function from fully executing before it hits 3000 milliseconds and displays the alert message?
}
```

the function timer() starts as the page loads but if I have a button for stopTime() and I click on it, how do I stop the first function from executing and stop it from hitting the 3000 millisecond mark and alerting "Out of time"?

Comment: You need to name your timer to a global var

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a variable with scope over all of your functions.

```
var myTimer;
...
myTimer = setTimeout(...);
...
clearTimeout(myTimer);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var timer;

function timer()
{
    timer = setTimeout(function(){alert("Out of time")}, 3000); //Alerts "Out of time" after 3000 milliseconds
}
function resetTime()
{
    clearTimeout(timer);
     timer(); //this is not right, i thought it would override the first function but it just adds another timer as well which is not what I want
}
function stopTime()
{
     //What could go here to stop the first function from fully executing before it hits 3000 milliseconds and displays the alert message?
}
```

try this it will Work For you

Comment: @colecmc sorry my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Its best to use the [useRef hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) from React

```
import {useRef} from 'React';


const function =()=>{
   const timerRef = useRef();


   const timerFunction =()=>{
      timerRef.current = setTimeout(()=>{
      //Your Code
      },5000);
`

  const clearTimerFunction =()=>{
       clearTimeout(timerRef.current);
      }

}
```

Comment: There is nothing to do with react in this question. The question is about javascript not react.

Answer (score -1):

The value returned from `setTimeout` is a unique ID that you can use later to cancel the timeout with `clearTimeout`.

```
var timeout;

function timer () {
    timeout = setTimeout(/* ... */);
}

function resetTime() {
    stopTime();
    timer();
}

function stopTime() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
}
```