# How to make sure the client called SignalR in a specific time?

Tags: c#, signalr

I'm using signalR in a two player online game. The player has maximum 30 seconds to perform his action in his turn, otherwise he will loose the game.

I tell the client to start:

```
public class GameHub : Hub
{
    public void AcceptRequest()
    {
        Clients.Client("connectionId").StartYourTurn();
    }

    public void Action(string id)
    {
           // player calls this method and I save it in a db.
    }
}
```

But how can I detect if the client didn't do anything in 30 seconds from SignalR side? Thanks.

Comment: what have you tried so far? at the moment I see that you want a code writing service to do this for you

Comment: @CodeWarrior Thanks for clarification for your down vote. But it's not clear what you mean by what I've tried. I've `SignalR` set up, and I send the client a start signal. then I need to know how to check the client called back signalR during 30 seconds. That's why I'm here.

Comment: Just set a 30 second timer in between requests, at the end of the timer fire off another request from the server that tells the client their time is up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's essentially the same answer as I gave you on your other question.

Start a 30 second countdown timer that is broadcast to the client each second. You don't have to show anything this time until you get to a point where you want to warn them their time is running out. Let's say at 10 seconds, then you show the 10 seconds remaining and/or a visual warning such as a color change somewhere in the UI. Then again at 5, 4, 3, 2, 1... maybe the colors get progressively closer to red (meaning time is up).

If you can't get that working then post that code, which is what I believe @CodeWarrior was referring to.

Comment: Thank you. I preferred not to make it heavy on the server, since this way, each second I have to check the database to see whether the client has sent an action to the server meanwhile or not. I've decided to check each ~5 seconds, and the client be responsible for the UI countdown itself.

Comment: If the client has sent anything in, you should be aware of that without having to check the database. The client should be calling a method in your hub when a client has performed an action.

Comment: yes the client calls a method in my hub, but how can the timer which is already fired be aware of that value without saving it first somewhere?

Comment: Making assumptions here, but if your UI is handling the countdown with a timer you want to clear that timer once a call to the method in the hub has been made. See this for clearing your timer from another function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30431590/how-to-stop-timer-with-another-function-javascript

Comment: well, the timer is on the server side, in my hub. Hub sends a signal each few seconds to the client for 30s to inform the client of remaining time. So meanwhile if the client call a hub method to perform an action, the timer should be aware somehow and get turned off. for that reason I save a flag in db when client calls the method, and timer checks that flag, if true, gets turned off.